# Why don't these elements log their ....style.backgroundColor in console, but I can successfully set it from the same console?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is just a red div. Nothing else. It does not do anything else.

When I log it to the console (as below) it has no style.backgroundColor. Yet I can successfully change the background color from console.

Why doesn't the original element logged in the console have a backgroundColor I can read?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32ohL51d/5/

```
    const target = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    console.log(target); // shows the correct element but it doesn't have a .style.backgroundColor

  // however if I go to console and run target.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; it works!

  // let's check if we're waiting for the DOM to get loaded or something, 
  // so we run the log 10 times, 3 seconds apart:

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout( () => {
            console.log(target.style.backgroundColor);
        }, 3000)
    } // returns empty string 10 times
```

```
<style>
    div { background-color: #f00; }
</style>
<div></div>
```

I can change it with `target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';` though. Why?

Comment: Because [`style` gives you the inline styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) and these elements don't have any (would look like `<div style="background-color: #f00;">` otherwise). Maybe you are looking for [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead.

Comment: That sounds right. Let me try it. Thanks